# Linux VM for Web Development on Windows Machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I currently do all my web development work in Windows using XAMPP. I am now looking to move this over to Linux because I'm finding it's more difficult to install / get hold of the correct tools for Windows. Plus a Linux environment would match a live server a lot closer.

As I am familiar with Windows, I would like to keep Windows as my "host" OS and run a Linux distro within a VM. I have the following questions in regards to this:

1. I have very little experience with Linux so I will need a distro that is easy to use, yet powerful enough to perform all the necessary web development tasks. What are the recommended options?
2. I would prefer to use my current editor in Windows. In which case, will I need to store my files on the host machine or on the VM? If on the VM, can I "map" the webroot folder as a drive so that I can access the files in Windows?
3. Will I be able to access the webserver on my host machine by going to `http://localhost`? And can I access the webserver from another machine by navigating to my host machine's IP address? Or do I need to configure something for this to work?

In essence, what I'm after is for the VM to run the web server, and nothing else. If I need to install an extension, such as ImageMagick I will do this in the VM.

Comment: Please, one question per question.  Also, your first question will only solicit opinion-based answers, and qualifies as a shopping suggestion request -- both those types of questions are off topic. Also, please do some research and try some stuff on your own first.

Comment: 2) yes and 3) yes, with configuration, but this is all explained in documentation. It takes little time to install a VM and give it a try, really.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use CentOS for my development server because it's easy enough to use and works nicely for most things I like to do. Choice of distro is almost always down to preference when it's only being used for testing. Pretty much anything that can run apache will do fine

I have my virtual machine setup with a samba share to the web directory to allow me to edit the file in windows.

I don't have much experience with virtualbox, but in VMWare the virtual machine gets it's own IP Address, either from a DHCP server or assigned by the Visualizer. The server is then accessed through that IP Address